# How I could model a slim cylindrical bottle with a dent on one side?

Tags: modeling

I tried posting around on various sites to get help creating a model similar to the images below. I'm trying to create a bottle shape that has curves that form cavities like the one in the image but I'm not sure how. Thanks! [image: reference image]

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand the cavity doesn't twirl around the object so you could probably do it with a cylinder that booleans another one, then apply and rework the topology:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I think the cavities do seem to curve around the cylinder, I think I may have to twist the cylinder then do a boolean.

Comment: I don't think so, the silhouette would have been different, do you have other pictures?

Comment: sure! I found an image from the side here: https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/3c05b557-be20-4cf4-a389-834232495e22.aa7a9cab42d545838edbe2214bd68a2f.jpeg?odnWidth=undefined&odnHeight=undefined&odnBg=ffffff

Comment: so to me it doesn't look like it goes around